# Writing a SQL Server query to unpack XML formatted data into individual colums

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a table named EventData.
This table has a column of XML type, the column name is XmlData.

XmlData contains data in the following format:

```xml
<Data>
  <Head>
    <Site>Site1</Site>
    <SourceID>9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706</SourceID>
    <SourceDescription>KU11</SourceDescription>
    <TimeStamp>2021-03-16T14:24:21.757Z</TimeStamp>
  </Head>
  <Details Template="EPMS.IProductionMachine">
    <Item>
      <Field>UnitMode</Field>
      <Value Type="Int32">1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>BatchId</Field>
      <Value Type="String">210316029</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>ProdProcessedCount</Field>
      <Value Type="Int32">2136</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>AlarmEventId</Field>
      <Values />
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>ProductId</Field>
      <Value Type="String">6824</Value>
    </Item>
  </Details>
</Data>
```

How can i write a SQL query that returns this data as induvidual colums?

Column names: `[SourceID, TimeStamp, UnitMode, BatchId, ProdProcessedCount, AlarmEventId, ProductId]`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Data>
  <Head>
    <Site>Site1</Site>
    <SourceID>9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706</SourceID>
    <SourceDescription>KU11</SourceDescription>
    <TimeStamp>2021-03-16T14:24:21.757Z</TimeStamp>
  </Head>
  <Details Template="EPMS.IProductionMachine">
    <Item>
      <Field>UnitMode</Field>
      <Value Type="Int32">1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>BatchId</Field>
      <Value Type="String">210316029</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>ProdProcessedCount</Field>
      <Value Type="Int32">2136</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>AlarmEventId</Field>
      <Values />
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Field>ProductId</Field>
      <Value Type="String">6824</Value>
    </Item>
  </Details>
</Data>';


SELECT 
  SourceId  = x1.X.value('(Data/Head/SourceID/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),
  ColumnTxt = x2.X.value('(Field/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  ColumnVal = x2.X.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM   (VALUES(@XML)) AS x1(X)
CROSS APPLY x1.X.nodes('/Data/Details/Item') AS x2(X);
```

**Returns:**

```
SourceId                                      ColumnTxt             ColumnVal
--------------------------------------------- --------------------- -------------
9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706          UnitMode              1
9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706          BatchId               210316029
9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706          ProdProcessedCount    2136
9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706          AlarmEventId          NULL
9A2AB8FD-3BED-4BFA-9A61-B9B41CC0F706          ProductId             6824
```

Answer (score 0):

The first couple of columns are very simple: `(Data/Head/SourceID/text())[1]` is pretty straight-forward.

The others are more involved:

```
(Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="BatchId"]/Value/text())[1]
```

This says to filter the `Item` node so that it has a matching child node named `Field` which has an inner text of `BatchId`.

`AlarmEventId` is unclear: do we have multiple nodes and we want to aggregate them, or do we only have one. I have given both options.

Note that `.value` requires a singleton node, so you need to use `[1]` to get the forst result only.

```sql
SELECT 
  SourceId     = x.xCol.value('(Data/Head/SourceID/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier'),
  [TimeStamp]  = x.xCol.value('(Data/Head/TimeStamp/text())[1]','datetime'),
  UnitMode     = x.xCol.value('(Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="UnitMode"]/Value/text())[1]', 'int'),
  BatchId      = x.xCol.value('(Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="BatchId"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  ProdProcessedCount= x.xCol.value('(/Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="ProdProcessedCount"]/Value/text())[1]', 'int'),
  AlarmEventIdAll = x.xCol.value('(for $a in Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="AlarmEventId"]/Values return concat(text()[1], "; "))[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
  AlarmEventId = x.xCol.value('(Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="AlarmEventId"]/Values/text())[1]', 'int'),
  ProductId    = x.xCol.value('(Data/Details/Item[Field/text()="ProductId"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM myTable x
```